# Error, operator of * must be pointer

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to calculate values of pi from 0 to 1-1/n with step 1/n, but c is not letting me multiply 2PI and my array of steps (error, operator of * must be a pointer). I'm new to c so if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI

int main(){
    int i;
    double in[256], out[256],n;
    n = 128.0000;
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++){
        in[i] = i / n;
        out[i] = sin(2*PI*in[i]);
        printf("%lf %lf \n", in[i],out[i]);
    }


    _getch();



}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#define PI
```

you don't define any value for `PI`, change this to

```
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
```

or

```
#define PI M_PI
```

if you are in the POSIX world (`math.h` also have to be included).

In your example, `PI` is just substituted with nothing and your assignment statement:

```
out[i] = sin(2*PI*in[i]);
```

ends up to :

```
out[i] = sin(2**in[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You define `PI` but you don't define it to *be* anything.  As a result, the token `PI` gets replaced with *nothing* in your code.  So this line:

```
out[i] = sin(2*PI*in[i]);
```

Becomes:

```
out[i] = sin(2**in[i]);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
out[i] = sin(2*(*in[i]));
```

Which means "get the `i`th element of the `in` array, dereference it, multiply the result by 2, and pass that to `sin()`.  But the `i`th element of the `in` array is a double, not a pointer type -- and this is why you get this particular error, because the operand to `*` is indeed not a pointer type.

You need to add a value for your `PI` definition:

```
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433
```